# Use brain.js neural network to do compare string and numbers from array

Tags: neural-network, brain.js

For learning and fun, I wanted to focus on brain.js, but with a different example than it's already described.
I have a problem, but probably with a bad approach to this library.

Namely, in a json I have book titles and their prices, while in a train I provide keywords and the price I can give for its occurrence in the title.

my JSON:

```
  [{ "title": "Bible js", "price": 30 }, 
  { "title": "Bible php", "price": 25 }, 
  { "title": "Bible java", "price": 40 }, 
  { "title": "All about js", "price": 25 }, 
  { "title": "Testing in php", "price": 50 }, 
  { "title": "How to start with java", "price": 40 }]
```

my code for brain.js:

```js
  const brain = require('brain.js');
  const jsonData = require('./books.json');

  const myMatch = [
    { input: ["js", 40], output: [1] },
    { input: ["php", 20], output: [1] },
    { input: ["How to", 50], output: [1] },
    { input: ["java", 0], output: [0] },
    { input: ["Bible", 0], output: [0] }
  ]

  var config = {
    binaryThresh: 0.5,     // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    hiddenLayers: [3],     // array of ints for the sizes of the hidden layers in the network
    activation: 'sigmoid' // Supported activation types ['sigmoid', 'relu', 'leaky-relu', 'tanh']
  }

  var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork(config);
  net.train(myMatch);
  jsonData.forEach(element => {
    let result = net.run(element.title, element.price);
    console.log('--element--');
    console.log(element.title, element.price);
    console.log('--typeof--');
    typeof result;
    console.log('--result--');
    console.log(result);
    console.log('--------------------');
  });
```

I load book titles and their prices and then I want it to return my degree of interest to given words and the price that interests me or not.

For example, I am looking for books about js for $40 and php for $20. I'm totally not interested in titles with "Bible" or "java".
The error I'm struggling with is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting NaN is you are feeding strings into the net where an array of numbers should go.  How many books are you classifying?

Comment: I have about 100 items like from example (JSON).  Is it possible to search:
1. the titles of the books by the words I am interested in
2. the prices I can give for them. 
On this basis calculate the match?

My point is that if in the title is "js" then i'm interested in it. However, if the price is very different from the price that I can give for it, my interest in it drops. If the title contains words that don't interest me at all( for example "java")then matching must be as close to 0 as possible. How can I compare it?